# How to change(Hide) the Nginx Server Signature?

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

I can hide NGINX version by using `server_tokens` option set to `off`. But not able to change the NGINX Server signature.

Steps I did:

1. Change the NGINX server name in source file **src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c** to  `My-Server`, then compiled NGINX.

But it is not working when I call the server. Strange here is I can see my updated Signature when I use `curl` command. But this is not updated in the browser.

2. I tried using a 3rd party module **headers-more-nginx-module**.

This doesn't work either. I am getting the updated name via **cURL** but not in browser.

Comment: Is this how you say "thanks" to developers of nginx?

Comment: may be your browser just cached the headers? try another browser or Ctrl-F5/Ctrl-R in you current one

Comment: @folibis , Yes, I checked on different browser. but still the same :(

Comment: @folibis  Yes, I've setup Nginx as a reverse proxy for apache LB. Do I need to change somewhere else?.

Comment: @VBart it's a minor way to improve security by leaking as little information as possible. Security through obscurity is an OK practice *after* making sure it's as secure as possible through design (i.e. it's patched and configured well).

Comment: If you want to minimize data leakage, you might want to customize redirect and error pages, too.

Answer (score 57):

If you are working in ubuntu then

1. First install `nginx-extras`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
   ```
2. Go to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and under `http` add:

   ```
   http {
       more_set_headers "Server: Your_New_Server_Name";
       server_tokens off; 
   }
   ```
3. Restart nginx

   ```
   sudo service nginx restart
   ```

Comment: 2020-01-18: Using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable` gives you `nginx/1.16.1` instead of `nginx/1.14.0` on `Ubuntu 18.04`. Have phun. https://observatory.mozilla.org/ https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ https://securityheaders.com/ https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html https://www.immuniweb.com/websec/

Answer (score 11):

1. Install `HttpHeadersMoreModule` - http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule
2. Change it using the `more_set_headers` directive.
3. Reload Nginx to take effect.

   ## Hide nginx version information.

   server_tokens       off;

   ## Change the server name.

   more_set_headers "Server: MyServerName";

Comment: Already tried this and explained the same on my 2nd point. Any other way to change it.

Comment: What version are you using? It requires at least v0.7.44.

Comment: @KMG  I was having the same problem using "more_set_headers".  The fact that it worked in "curl" indicated it worked.  Turned out the browser was caching the requests.  Once I cleared that up the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 11):

Go to nginx conf and switch off server_tokens.

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

server_tokens off;
```

Comment: [This only removes the version number, not the `Server` header or the name "nginx"](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens)! Further, you should mention where to add the config option to (e.g. to `http`, `server` or `location`)

Answer (score 9):

You can use this in your Nginx config.

```
proxy_pass_header Server;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? This works if you are reverse proxying some backend server. Is there some other case where this would work?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue.
In the server part, I added

`server_tokens off;`   // This will remove version

And in the HTTP part added

`proxy_pass_header Server;`  //Server name and version will be hidden

Final nginx.conf file looks like :

```
server {
        listen 9090;

       server_tokens off;

        location / {
                access_log off;
                add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                return 200;
        }
        location /test {
                rewrite /test/(.*) /$1  break;
                proxy_pass         http://localhost:9090;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;

                proxy_pass_header Server;

                client_max_body_size 200M;
                proxy_connect_timeout      240;
                proxy_send_timeout         240;
                proxy_read_timeout         240;
        }
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If using ModSecurity v2.0 - v2.9, then in the .conf file you can use

```
SecServerSignature SomeName
```

ModSecurity v3 SecServerSignature has been deprecated, but I don't know if they replaced it with something else.