# how to change server host name in nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, centos7, nginx-config

I am trying to launch nginx server in port 80 using a different hostname.

Currently, port 80 is bound by Apache, and in fact, I have other sites in the server, which is CentOS 7.

I need to launch ngix using the same port but other virtual host, which is not managed by Apache.

I tried by modifying the fila: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf which has this lines:

```
listen       hostname:80;
server_name  hostname;
```

But it did not work. And even, I changed port to 8080 to test, but when I run "systemctl status nginx.service" it always responds with:

```
 nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-03-11 20:32:52 -03; 7min ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 22790 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 11 20:32:49 vps.desytec.com nginx[22790]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 11 20:32:50 vps.desytec.com nginx[22790]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 11 20:32:50 vps.desytec.com nginx[22790]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 11 20:32:51 vps.desytec.com nginx[22790]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 11 20:32:51 vps.desytec.com nginx[22790]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 11 20:32:52 vps.desytec.com nginx[22790]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Mar 11 20:32:52 vps.desytec.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 11 20:32:52 vps.desytec.com systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Mar 11 20:32:52 vps.desytec.com systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Mar 11 20:32:52 vps.desytec.com systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

Finally, this is the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
user  nginx;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    client_max_body_size 64m;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=16k;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    keepalive_requests 100;

    #gzip  on;



    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*;
}
```

Any help, please?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Asking two different applications to share the same IP address and port will not work.

Comment: You can't run both Apache and nginx on the same port. You said you changed to 8080 and still couldn't get it working, but your service status still mentions port 80. I suggest you change all the `hostname:80;` to `hostname:8080;` and try. Or stop Apache and then try using nginx.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594971/how-to-changehide-the-nginx-server-signature/74614935#74614935 You take help from here.