# How to remove header server nginx

Tags: nginx

Using ubuntu server 20.04, nginx version: nginx/1.17.10 (Ubuntu), localhost,
when I shut down my dot net application, "502 Bad Gateway" following by nginx appears ( version is hidden successfully). I did this to hide nginx:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
http {
more_set_headers "Server: Your_New_Server_Name";
server_tokens off; }
sudo service nginx restart
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594971/how-to-changehide-the-nginx-server-signature/38967105#38967105)

Even tried

```
more_clear_headers Server; 
more_set_input_headers -r 'Server: howdy';
```

but still having problem. All the web suggest just the same way, but not working to me.

My currently nginx.conf :

```
user ehsan1362;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}
http {
        
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    server_tokens off;
    # more_clear_headers Server;
    #more_set_input_headers -r 'Server: howdy';    
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";



 server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: How does your `nginx.conf` look at the moment? Maybe you added it in the wrong place in the file.

Comment: I added my current nginx.conf  but most of the commented lines are omitted.

Comment: Wait a second, I realize now, are you really talking about the `Server` HTTP header, or about the error page footer? If it's the latter, you can just define your own error pages (like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04), or check out [this](https://blog.adriaan.io/one-nginx-error-page-to-rule-them-all.html) to set one page for all errors)

Comment: It solved my problem :) I just wanted to hide word "nginx" and now I can manage it by your favor.

Comment: @ehsan_kabiri_33 Could you please post the solution?

Comment: Cristian Rodriguez, please check `CherryDT` comment. The complete answer to have an error page instead of showing something like `Bad gate way/nginx`